# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InitFont'

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

Run on Python 2.7 OpenCV 3.2 Windows 10 
The below code is throwing [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6hBe.png)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InitFont'

My best guess is due to OpenCV 3 as it was working fine in below version.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
recognizer.load('trainner/trainner.yml')
cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.InitFont(cv2.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
while True:
    ret, im =cam.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2,5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(225,0,0),2)
        Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        if(conf<50):
            if(Id==1):
                Id="Prosper"

        else:
            Id="Unknown"
        cv2.cv.PutText(cv2.cv.fromarray(im),str(Id), (x,y+h),font, 255)
    cv2.imshow('im',im) 
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The error is "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InitFont'

"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You no longer need to initialize the font; the `cv` module is deprecated, everything you need should come from `cv2`. In the `cv2` api, images are arrays, so you don't need to convert `fromarray`. The syntax is a bit different for calling the `putText` function as well.

See the documentation for `putText` here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html#cv2.putText

This should work for you. Be sure to delete the `InitFont` function in the beginning of your program.

```
fontface = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontscale = 1
fontcolor = (255, 255, 255)
cv2.putText(im, str(Id), (x,y+h), fontface, fontscale, fontcolor)
```

---

Edit: Here's a minimal working example adding text onto frames from `VideoCapture` using `putText`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fontFace = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontScale = 1
fontColor = (255, 255, 255)

ret, im = cam.read()
locy = int(im.shape[0]/2) # the text location will be in the middle
locx = int(im.shape[1]/2) #           of the frame for this example

while True:
    ret, im = cam.read()
    cv2.putText(im, "Success!", (locx, locy), fontFace, fontScale, fontColor) 
    cv2.imshow('im', im)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but Its showing another error that im is not defined.

Comment: @prosperpatel can you edit the OP to show your current code? Your syntax is correct for reading the frames. I'll edit my post with a MWE that puts text on a video captured frame, hopefully that will help!

Comment: thanks @Alexander that error is solved. But it show another error that Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Minor\train\recognize.py", line 27, in <module>
    cv2.PutText(cv2.fromarray(im),str(Id), (x,y+h),font, 255)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PutText'

Comment: In the `cv` module the functions were written with UpperCamelCase and now they're lowerCamelCase: it should be `cv2.putText(...)`. Also in the `cv2` module, images are already arrays, so you don't need to use `cv2.fromarray(im)`, just simply use `im`. Please see my edited answer for the correct syntax.

Comment: thanks for suggestion @Alexander, i changed line 27 to "cv2.putText(im, str(Id), (x,y+h),font,255)"    but its showing 
NameError: name 'font' is not defined

Comment: Right, I set the font parameters above my loop (fontFace, fontSize, fontColor). Or, you could simply change line 27 to `cv2.putText(im,str(Id), (x,y+h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255))`. The `1` is for the scale (so you can make it bigger or smaller by changing that) and the `(255,255,255)` is the color, so you could change it from white if you wanted.

Comment: thanks @Alexander the code work fine. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the another way to handle the error.

cv2.putText(img,text,(x,y+h),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,(255,255,255))