# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cv'

Tags: python, opencv

I think I have some issues with the windows system or python 3.6 version. I am facing some attribute error. I have checked and double checked my code and there is no error and i also compare my code to others and i have seen there is no error. then why i am facing this kind of error. I am adding my code here:

[image: recognizer module]

and i am facing following error.

> C:\Users\MAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
>   C:/Users/MAN/PycharmProjects/facerecognition/Recognise/recognizerr.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/MAN/PycharmProjects/facerecognition/Recognise/recognizerr.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       font =  cv2.cv.InitFont(cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1) AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cv'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Is this the Windows issue or it shows only error in Python 3.6 version? 
for you kind information I am using Python 3.6 in Windows platform.

Comment: Please do *not* post a *screenshot* of the code, but the *actual* code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InitFont'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021999/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-initfont)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

in Opencv3 the `cv` module is deprecated. So, in line 11 you can initialize the font like following:

```
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
```

Answer (score 7):

`font = cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX`

I worked on different variable (`CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH`), and it took me soo long to understand that you also need to remove the "CV_".

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
as the best answer suggested.

Comment: Format code as code in your answer for clarity